# How you'd show that $f$ is not continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

How do you show that 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}2,&x < c\\1,&x\geq c\end{cases}$$ is not continuous at $c$ by using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ - formalism like [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function)?

Comment: Have you tried something already? You need to pick a small $\varepsilon$, and show that the function jumps by more than $\varepsilon$ in any interval around $c$, however small.

Comment: So it is proof by counter-example?

Comment: Essentially yes (see vadim123's answer). The definition is that for any $\varepsilon$ there must exist a $\delta$ with a certain property, so you can show it fails by exhibiting a particular $\varepsilon$ such that there is no corresponding $\delta$ with the right property. In other words, the negation of "for all $\varepsilon$ there exists $\delta$ such that $P$" is "there exists $\varepsilon$ such that $\neg P$ holds for all $\delta$", which can be proved by finding such an $\varepsilon$ explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f$ were continuous.  Let $\epsilon=0.1$, and $\delta$ be chosen so that $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$ for all $|x-c|<\delta$. But $|(c-\delta/2)-c|<\delta$ and $|f(c-\delta/2)-f(c)|=|2-1|=1>\epsilon$.  Contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You must show that there exists an $\epsilon>0$ so that no matter what $\delta>0$ you choose, $0<\lvert x-c\rvert<\delta$ is not enough to say that $\lvert f(x)-f(c)\rvert<\epsilon$.

That is, there exists an $\epsilon>0$ so that for any $\delta>0$, you can find a point $x$ which is within $\delta$ of $c$ but satisfies $\lvert f(x)-f(c)\rvert\geq\epsilon$.

You can find points as close to $c$ as you want which have $f(x)=2$, so that $\lvert f(x)-f(c)\rvert=1$.  How should you choose $\epsilon$?

Comment: well maybe $\epsilon=1/2$? At least less than 1.

Comment: @laovultai Exactly right! You can find points $x$ arbitrarily close to $c$ so that $\lvert f(x)-f(c)\rvert\geq\frac{1}{2}$ (or, as you say, any constant in $(0,1)$).

Answer (score 2):

You need to show that there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that for any $\delta>0$, you can find some $x$ with $|x-c|< \delta$ so that $|f(x)-f(c)| \ge \epsilon$.

In this particular case, this means finding some $\epsilon>0$ such that for any $\delta>0$, you can find some $x$ with $|x-c|< \delta$ so that $|f(x)-1| \ge \epsilon$.

If you draw a picture it may help find appropriate $\epsilon$ and $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Reword the definition:

$f$ is not continuous at $x_0$ if there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $\delta > 0$, there exists an $x$ such that $|x-x_0| < \delta$ but $|f(x) - f(x_0)| > \epsilon$.

Now, let $x_0 = c$, take $\epsilon = 1/2$ (other choices will work), and then show that for every $\delta > 0$, there exists an $x$...

Comment: So you negate everything in this definition but leave $|x−x_0 |< \delta$ (1)? Why not also negate this (1)? Or do you mean that rewording is same as negating everything else, but (1)?

Comment: Let me use parentheses to indicate each piece of the definition of continuity: ($\forall \epsilon > 0$) ($\exists \delta$) such that ($|x - x_0|<\delta$) implies ($|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$). The negation of this is ($\exists \epsilon > 0$) such that ($\forall \delta$), ($|x - x_0|<\delta$) does *not* imply ($|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$). Demonstrating this is the same as demonstrating the statement I gave in my answer.